# Is it valid to use additional url query params to prevent cahing or force update css/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, server

Is it ok to use additional url query params to prevent cahing or force update css/js?

```
/style.css?v=1
```

Or it will be better to change name of file/dir?

```
/style.1.css
```

I heard this something affects the ability of proxy servers to download styles/scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use different file names so you can see different versions/changes directly in your project.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use different version names.If you want to make sure they always have a new version, than have your build system add a build number to the end of the file.

If Different file name "you need to change file name every deployment."

Answer (score 0):

server put on header

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-transform
Cache-Control: public
Cache-Control: private
Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
Cache-Control: max-age=<seconds>
Cache-Control: s-maxage=<seconds>
```

[for more details "no-cahe" on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)